# How to painless installing of external packages for Python?

Tags: python, package, installation, external

I have used Anaconda+Spyder and also Pycharm for python code developments. I am having difficulties with installing external packages, using either CONDA or PIP. It is very common for me to see error regarding conflict between the packages and versions. Is there a painless, hassle-free approach to install a set of compatible external libraries for python?

Comment: One of Anacondas main pro's should be that it handles these dependencies between packages (by automatically installing them as well and/or up- or downgrading their versions). With PIP you need to handle this yourself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using virtual environments is a convenient way to avoid version conflicts.

[Conda envs](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html)

[venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful.